# Is Perl's GetOpt::Long accepting abbreviations of switches a bug?

Tags: perl, getopt

This is a simple script I have written to test command line argument handling:

```
use Getopt::Long;

my $help = 0;

GetOptions(
'help|h|?' => \$help,
) or die "Error!";

print "OK\n";
```

The results I got are as follows:

```
D:\>perl test.pl --help
OK

D:\>perl test.pl --hell
Unknown option: hell
Error! at test.pl line 10.

D:\>perl test.pl --he
OK

D:\>perl test.pl --hel
OK
```

Has anybody noticed this before? Is the behaviour (accepting he and hel instead of help) a potential bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's intentional.  It accepts the shortest non-ambiguious version of the option, so if you had another option "--hex", it wouldn't accept "--he" but it would accept "--hel".

Answer (score 13):

it is a feature documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Case-and-abbreviations)

Answer (score 8):

This is a [feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Case-and-abbreviations). Options may be abbreviated as long as the result is not ambiguous. If you don't want this behavior it is possible to disable it via [configuration](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Configuring-Getopt%3a%3aLong).

If this were a bug, the place to check to find out whether or not it was a known one is the [bug queue](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Getopt-Long) at [rt.cpan.org](http://rt.cpan.org).

Comment: for reference, an example of disabling `auto_abbrev` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787024/getoptions-in-perl-does-not-validate-full-argument-names