# GetOptions() in perl does not validate full argument names

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, getopt-long

Suppose I want to enter 2 command line parameters - source and destination.
GetOptions allows the command line by checking only the first character of the argument name instead of the full string.
How do I validate for the full arguments strings instead of just allowing its substrings to be passed?

Here's an example program:

```
my ($source,$dest);
GetOptions(
'from=s' => \$source,
'to=s' => \$dest
) or die "Incorrect arguments\n";
```

It accepts any of:

- `-from`
- `-fro`
- `-fr`
- `-f`
- `-to`
- `-t`

However, I want it to accept only

- `-from`
- `-to`

and fail if anything except those full words is passed.

How can I disallow the abbreviated options?

Answer (score 9):

By default, abbreviations are enabled.  Disable `auto_abbrev`.  Refer to  [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Configuring-Getopt%3A%3ALong):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_auto_abbrev);

my ($source,$dest);
GetOptions(
'from=s' => \$source,
'to=s' => \$dest
) or die "Incorrect arguments\n";
```

For example, when `-fro` is passed, this dies with the message:

```
Unknown option: fro
Incorrect arguments
```

Comment: I recommend `use Getopt::Long qw( :config posix_default );` instead; it provides saner defaults including `no_auto_abbrev`. Specifically, it's equivalent to `use Getopt::Long qw( :config no_auto_abbrev no_getopt_compat require_order );`, so `-fro` isn't allowed, `+from` isn't allowed, and mixing options and argument isn't allowed.

Answer (score 5):

See "Configuring `Getopt::Long`" in the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long#Configuring-Getopt::Long):

> #### `auto_abbrev`
>
> Allow option names to be abbreviated to uniqueness. Default
>                   is enabled unless environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` has
>                   been set, in which case "`auto_abbrev`" is disabled.